# creating yaml file from image for mobile robot navigation

Tags: ros, yaml, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone.
i need help on creating yaml file. i have to create a yaml file from an image(map of surrounding) and then used the yaml file for turtlebot navigation.
anyone know where can i start?is it very difficult to be done?i have no basic of programming.
please help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199881/creating-yaml-file-from-image-for-mobile-robot-navigation/) by [lfyhmdn](https://answers.ros.org/users/20052/lfyhmdn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am not sure what you mean by creating a yaml file from an image, but you can find all the necessary yaml files for turtlebot navigation [here](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/hydro/turtlebot_navigation/param).

---

Originally posted by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) with karma: 651 on 2014-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0